# how to track URL of external site with $window

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ionic application that is acting as a sort of container for a web application. The user logs in from the ionic app and the app opens an external url loading the web app. code is below.

```
var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('portal[username]',user.name);
        formData.append('portal[password]',user.password);
        formData.append('portal[From]','web');

        var url = API_ENDPOINT.url + '/login';
        var xhr = createCORSRequest('POST', url);

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
          if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200)
          {
            var  jsonObj =   JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            var  status  =   jsonObj.status;
            var  message =   jsonObj.message;

            if(status==='success')
            {
              var token = jsonObj.token;
              home = 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/map/index?token='+token;
              $window.open(home, '_blank','location=yes,toolbar=yes');
            }
            else
            {
              reject(message)
            }
          }
        };
        xhr.send(formData);
```

I have two issues i have been trying to solve. The first is that when the web app is loaded, the new window takes over the entire ionic view, i want to still be able to view my ionic header and footer.
 Secondly i want to be able to track the users location in the external app, to make certain events happen when certain URL's are loaded.i've tried using the 'loadstart' event but its not working for me or i'm not using it right.